# Make full page white

Tags: html, css

My website is currently like this on little screens:
http://d.pr/i/KwI8+

And on big screens it's like
http://d.pr/i/ckmF+

But I need to have it like this:
http://d.pr/i/IJc7+

Live demo is on http://www.random-radio.net/

CSS

```
html, body{
    width:100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;        
    height:100%;

    margin:0 !important;
    padding:0 !important;
    opacity: 0.99;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

    background-color: #cfcfcf;
}

#page
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;
    width: 1024px;
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: #FFF;
    /*margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;*/
}
```

I want a `div` from the top of the page to the bottom of the page.
I'm currently trying to use the above CSS, but on a screen that is higher than the content of the `div`, the background gets the `#cfcfcf` background of the body

Comment: Please post a specific question, post some code, and read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Please post your *relevant* code here. That way you would still have a question in here once the link goes down. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a `div` that has a `height: 100%` and a background of `#ffffff`.

```
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%;}
#page {margin: 0 auto; width: 1024px; height: 100%; background-color: #ff0000;}
```

### [See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X943y/)

Comment: Not working for me, when I make the `screen` lower. I get a half background.